# Untangle the comb of sentences...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here I have such a problem:

---

Mister Alex, his wife Bianca and three children Carmen, Dan and Ela, are sitting together:
(a)

a. If Mister Alex watches Tv, the same does his wife;

b. Or Dan, or Ela, or both are watching TV;

c. Or Bianca, or Carmen, but not both are watching TV;

d. Dan and Carmen, either watch TV or not, but only together;

e. If Ela watches TV, then and mister Alex and Dan watch.

Who is and isn't watching TV ?

---

I've tried to use the logic equivalences for this problem. First, I noted the sentences>

```
1. Mister Alex watches TV;
2. His wife Bianca watches TV;
3. Carmen watches Tv;
4. Dan watches TV;
5. Ela watches TV;
```

---

Then , I made the proposition using different operation and obtained the following:

(a)$A \to B$

(b)$D\oplus E\oplus(D\land E)$;

(c)$(B\land \lnot C)\oplus (\lnot B \land C )$;

(d)$(D \land C) \oplus (\lnot D \land \lnot C)$

(e)$E \to (A \land D)$;

---

Then, after I made the right simplifications to the sentences above, i got:

(a) $\lnot A \lor B$;

(b)$D \lor E$ ;

(c)$(B\land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot D \lor \lnot C)$ ;

(d)$(D\land C ) \lor (\lnot D \land \lnot C)$;

(e)$\lnot E \to (A \land D)$

---

The whole sentence(E) can be formed:
$E=(\lnot A \lor B) \land [(B\land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot D \lor \lnot C)] \land [(D\land C ) \lor (\lnot D \land \lnot C)] \land [\lnot E \to (A \land D)]$

Now , the problem is I do not know how to simplify $E$. Can you please help me figure out how can I do this ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: The idea is good. I have not checked the details. A machine might like this formulation. A human, not so much.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But do you have an idea how can I solve this problem using logic equivalence,  and not the table with zeros and ones ?Since its so composed is there any other possibility to do this ?

Comment: There must be programs somewhere on the web that carry out SAT.